# React Native : Updating state when props change and internally through setState()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a parent component that passes an array of data to a child component as a prop (the child component saves this array prop as part of its own state), and I want the child's state to update when this prop changes.

I used getDerivedStateFromProps as such :

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.messages != state.messages) {
        return {
            messages : [ ... props.messages]
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I also want to be able to update the state within the child, through `setState()`.
However, when I call `setState()` to update `this.state.messages`, the change isn't reflected (presumably because changes to this.state.messages only occur when the props change, as I've overridden `getDerivedStateFromProps()`)

Is there any way I can update the child's state for `this.state.messages` BOTH when the props change, AND when I want to update it within the child?

My constraints :

- I can't isolate the ownership of data to only one of the parent or child
- I expect others to use this component, so I don't want them to have to pass a function from the parent as a prop to update the parent's source of data within the child component

Comment: Check this example, probably you find something useful https://jsbin.com/wasequt/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent state is passed to the child component as props. Try using **shouldComponentUpdate** method in the child component.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
if(nextProps.messages.length > this.props.messages.length)
    return true
return true;
}
```

Now use the **componentDidUpdate** to update your state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
      if (this.props.messages.length !== prevProps.messages.length) {
        this.setState({
        messages: this.props.messages
        )}
      }
    }
```

Comment: This almost works, but for some reason, the child component is one props transition behind (when the prop is at state x, the child has the prop value at state x - 1) Any ideas as to why?

Comment: The nextProps.messages in shouldComponentUpdate and this.props.messages in componentDidUpdate should match :/

Comment: Oh, actually it does match! But it seems that this.setState({messages : this.props.messages)} isn't updating the state properly with the new props - the state change happens only the next time the props change for some reason

Comment: May I suggest you to convert your child component to functional component. This way you can easily update your state in function component:

const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
 setMessages(props.messages)
}, [props.messages])

Comment: Oh one more thing - adding forceUpdate() after the setState call works

Comment: I have updated the shouldComponentUpdated method. Try updating yours

Comment: When we setState we were not returning true which was not causing it to update. It should work without forceUpdate now